# How to configure Apache to use these files for SSL?

Tags: ssl, apache2

I know this looks like a old question, but my situation is that I have different file names in respect to what I expected and to what I see in the actual Apache2 configuration, so I need a more precise answer, if possible.

I got these files from my SSL cert provider

- DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.crt
- mydomain.it.crt
- mydomain.it.csr
- mydomain.it.key
- mydomain.it.pfx
- RapidSSL_TLS_RSA_CA_G1.crt

Actually my apache is configured as

```
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl-conf/mydomain.it.key
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl-conf/mydomain.it.cer
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl-conf/intermediate.cer
```

I don't know which file associate to each item

Well, keyfile is, obviously, the .key.
But which is the right .crt for CertificateFile and which for CertificateChainFile?

EDIT

I read https://www.ssl247.it/support/install/apache and I think I must user mydomain.it.crt as SSLCertificateFile

Last doubt is: what is intermediate.cer equivalent in my situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl-conf/mydomain.it.key
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl-conf/mydomain.it.crt
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl-conf/intermediate.crt
```

Where intermediate.crt is created by concatenating the content of `DigiCert_Global_Root_G2.crt` and `RapidSSL_TLS_RSA_CA_G1.crt`

Also, please remember that extensions do not matter, they are just for conveninence of human user/administrator. Only the content matters.